# .class file of static nested class on compiling Outer class can't be used via association but can be used via inheritance. why?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have an outer class and a static nested class as

```
class Outer {
  static int x = 20;
  static class Nested {
    static void show() {
      System.out.println(x);
    }
  }
}
```

on compiling this program ,I've got two .class files named: 
Outer.class and Outer$Nested.class .

Now my question is ,I am trying to use the Outer$Nested.class in my other class Test1 (using association).

```
class Test1 {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Outer$Nested i = new Outer$Nested();
  }
}
```

It gives me compile time error : can't find symbol Outer$Nested.
And I know we can use static nested class directly as Outer.Nested, but I am just trying this.
But when I am trying to use this class via Inheritance then it is compiling and running fine.

```
class Temp2 extends Outer$Inner {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    show();
  }
}
```

Now compiling and running fine , output : 20

So my question is why it is happening that we aren't able to use Outer$Nested via association and event we can't declare variable , but can use via inheritance ?

Comment: Try using "Outer.Nested i = new Outer.Nested();"

Comment: I know how to instantiate nested class, but I am just asking how this is happening that I asked

Comment: I just find out that if using command line `javac` to compile instead of Eclipse, the second case can be compiled. For the first case, if you change it to `new Outer$Nested().show();`, it can also be compiled and executed. That's weird. However, in normal case, we don't use this name in coding.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know how the inheritance concepts works like your way, but want to create instance of the inner nested class use this lines of codes

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Outer.Nested obj= new Outer.Nested();
    obj.show();
 }
```

Comment: I know how to instantiate nested class ,but I am just asking how this is happening . Why this behaviour of java ?

Comment: It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place,It increases encapsulation,It can lead to more readable and maintainable code ., refer here for more information and behaviour of  java nested 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html